# Fail to pass user input to wget in python

Tags: python, wget

I would like to pass user input to wget to download content of a web page.

```
  User_input = raw_input "Type a URL Here.. "

  os.system("wget -O /directory/, User_input")
```

The code above did not work because wget will not take the user input, but it will wget "User_input" instead. Is there a way round this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually passing the variable, also use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
from subprocess import check_call

User_input = raw_input("Type a URL Here.. ")

check_call(["wget", "-O", "directory/foo.html", User_input])
```

In your code you would need to actually pass the variable:

```
 os.system("wget -O /directory  {}".format(User_input))
```

If your command returns a non-zero exit status you will get a `CalledProcessError` using `check_call`.

The easiest way to save the file is to let the user pick the name and add the extension. You could parse the url passed but there are too many possible variations to do it consistently:

```
User_input = raw_input("Type a URL Here.. ")
save_as = raw_input("Enter name to save file as...")

check_call(["wget", "-O", "{}.html".format(save_as), User_input])
```

Comment: I think, your string in `os.system` is declared badly: you're using both `"` and `'`

Comment: @ForceBrum yes a typo, the command should not be used at all.  The subprocess module should always be used

Comment: Yes. I was just writing a comment about the need of a space between the path name and the braces :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you for your suggestions, the code worked for me. Just one more question, how do you make it saves with the user_input name? So for example, if you type google.com, it then saves the output to google.html file.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, Thank you again for your quick help but it didnt seem to work correctly. Though, it saved with the user input name but the file contained wget information (download process) rather than the the website's html content, as this was saved with another file name called "index.html"

Comment: @i3echod, sorry had a typo,  if you just want to save the html there are numerous easy ways to save the html using python.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, this code os.system("wget -O /directory  {}".format(User_input)) did the job. It downloaded the actual web content but I cannot get it to save with the User_input file name.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, Thanks it now works. But how to make it to save within a directory? Because when I tried adding /directory/User_input after .format, it gave me a syntax error.

Comment: `check_call(["wget", "-O", "/path/{}.html".format(save_as), User_input])` should not give you any error, obviously the path must exist though

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, Thank you for all of your helps. I am very appreciated.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, Sorry to trouble you again, I am now working on phishing website detection and am trying to wget phishtank website to get some of its content. However, it returned me with "Your client has been blocked, please contact support". Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your ip has probably been blocked , do they have anything in their terms of service about scraping?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, Honestly, I do not know abot that. Have you tried and got it to work? And if it did work on your, how to fix it on mine?

Comment: what is the exact url you are trying to get?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, lets says this one https://www.phishtank.com/phish_detail.php?phish_id=3080476

Answer (score 0):

Have you at least tried to learn some Python? Your code has *lots* of problems.

- `raw_input "Something"` is not valid. You need to use `raw_input("User input: ")`
- you're using the `os` module without importing it first
- you're trying to pass a value to `wget` wrongly, it's better to do like this `cmd="wget -O /directory/ "+User_input;os.system(cmd)`

Comment: I was unable to format the code properly: it doesn't get formatted after an unordered list. Why?

Comment: why are you casting a string to a string? Also os.system should be avoided

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, yep, that's odd, but I sometimes do this just to be sure.

Comment: raw_input always returns a string unless you explicitly casts so you are safe without casting